# Collision Detection and Arrays (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array full of bitmaps of spikes and I'm wanting to detect when those spikes collide with the character bitmap. I've read this: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

But how would I implement that when I'm using an array to store the spike bitmaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the `redClipBmpData.hitTest` part? Just put it inside the array loop:

```
var total:uint = bitmaps.length; // bitmaps is the array

for (var i:uint = 0; i < total; i++) {
    var bitmap:Bitmap = bitmaps[i];
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = bitmap.bitmapData;

    bitmapData.hitTest(...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. That works but is very expensive because there are a lot of spike bitmaps. Would there be any way of optimising it to improve performance? EDIT: Just figured out that it only works with the final bitmap in the array. Any idea why this could be?

Comment: What do you mean by 'only the final bitmap'? If you mean the last, there should be some problem when inserting those bitmaps in that array..